# Best way to train for a relay

Tags: tips, racing

I am 12 years old and we have a school-wide relay champiniship and I was wondering what is the best tips to train in a 4x100m relay.

So I was wondering how do you train for a relay.

UPDATE: We won by a few secs on now we are in Dictrect Aths relay team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to practice doing sprints, the 100m shouldn't be too long a distance. You can start smaller and practice doing 50m sprints and then build up.

You should also make sure you get a decent amount of sleep the two nights before the event.

Because you will be doing sprints, during training and before the event I suggest you do a reasonable amount of warming up and stretches.

There is also another exercise where you sprint about 10 - 15 metres, touch the ground then sprint back another 10 - 15 metres and do several repetitions. So you are practising taking off from a point.

Comment: Thanks for that and also do you know what is the best way to do the change. We are pretty good but I want to know another way of changing.

Comment: @Benny - Youtube is your friend here. Look at how the athletes do it and then practice with your team. You don't need to practice the full 100m to practice the handover. What you do need to look at is slowing down and the grip and look at where they are looking as they hand the baton over.